# Get Phone Number From Android Contact Book

Tags: java, android

I wants to get Phone Number form Contact Book of Android. i tried many methods but i am unable to get Phone Number. i got Contact Name and Status but when i try to get Phone Number it don't works.
My Code is.

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends GroupingCursorAdapter {
    public static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
        Phone._ID,
        Phone.LOOKUP_KEY,
        Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
        Phone.CONTACT_STATUS,
        Phone.TIMES_CONTACTED,
        Phone.LAST_TIME_CONTACTED,
        Phone.STARRED,
        Phone.NUMBER

    };
    public static final int COLUMN_PHONE_ID = 0;
    public static final int COLUMN_LOOKUP_KEY = 1;
    public static final int COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME = 2;
    public static final int COLUMN_CONTACT_STATUS = 3;
    public static final int COLUMN_TIMES_CONTACTED = 4;
    public static final int COLUMN_LAST_TIME_CONTACTED = 5;
    public static final int COLUMN_STARRED = 6;
    public static final int COLUMN_NUMER=7;

    private class ViewCache {
        public final TextView contactName;
        public final TextView contactLastDialed;
        public final TextView contactInformation;
        public final TextView contactCallCount;
        public final ImageView contactImage;
        public final ImageView contactStarred;

        public ViewCache(View base) {
            contactName = (TextView)base.findViewById(R.id.ContactName);
            contactLastDialed = (TextView)base.findViewById(R.id.ContactLastDialed);
            contactInformation = (TextView)base.findViewById(R.id.ContactInformation);
            contactCallCount = (TextView)base.findViewById(R.id.ContactCallCount);
            contactImage = (ImageView)base.findViewById(R.id.ContactImage);
            contactStarred = (ImageView)base.findViewById(R.id.ContactStarred);
        }

    }


    private Resources mResources;
    private AsyncContactImageLoader mAsyncContactImageLoader;
    private boolean mShowCallCounter;

    public ContactsAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, AsyncContactImageLoader asyncContactImageLoader) {
        super(context, cursor, Phone.LOOKUP_KEY);
        mResources = context.getResources();
        mAsyncContactImageLoader = asyncContactImageLoader;
        mShowCallCounter = false;
    }


    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (shouldBeGrouped(cursor)) { // we just hide the grouped views
            View view = new View(context);
            view.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
            return view;
        }
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contact_item, null);
        ViewCache viewCache = new ViewCache(view);
        view.setTag(viewCache);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        final ViewCache viewCache = (ViewCache)view.getTag();
        if (viewCache == null) { // empty view has no viewcache, and we do nothing with it
            return;
        }
        String displayName = cursor.getString(COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME);
        if (displayName == null) {
            displayName = "";
        }

        viewCache.contactName.setText(displayName);

        long lastTimeContacted = cursor.getLong(COLUMN_LAST_TIME_CONTACTED);
        if (lastTimeContacted == 0) {
            viewCache.contactLastDialed.setText(mResources.getString(R.string.not_contacted));
        } else {
            viewCache.contactLastDialed.setText(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(lastTimeContacted));
        }      
savedInstanceState;
        String number= cursor.getString(COLUMN_NUMBER);
        if (status == null) {
            number= "03324004738 Dummy";
        }

        status = status.replace('\n', ' ');
        viewCache.contactInformation.setText(status);

        int timesContacted = cursor.getInt(COLUMN_TIMES_CONTACTED);
        if (mShowCallCounter) {
            viewCache.contactCallCount.setText("(" + timesContacted + ")");
        } else {
            viewCache.contactCallCount.setText("");
        }

        int starred = cursor.getInt(COLUMN_STARRED);
        viewCache.contactStarred.setVisibility(starred == 1? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

        String lookupKey = cursor.getString(COLUMN_LOOKUP_KEY);
        if (lookupKey == null) { // should absolutely never happen
            lookupKey = "";
        }
        viewCache.contactImage.setTag(lookupKey); // set a tag for the callback to be able to check, so we don't set the contact image of a reused view
        Drawable d = mAsyncContactImageLoader.loadDrawableForContact(lookupKey, new ImageCallback() {

            @Override
            public void imageLoaded(Drawable imageDrawable, String lookupKey) {
                if (lookupKey.equals(viewCache.contactImage.getTag())) {
                    viewCache.contactImage.setImageDrawable(imageDrawable);
                }
            }
        });
        viewCache.contactImage.setImageDrawable(d);
    }

    public void setShowCallCounter(boolean showCallCounter) {
        mShowCallCounter = showCallCounter;
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried Long for Getting Number insted of String..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you can get correct contact `lookupkey`. Here is my code. You can test it.

```
private static final String[] PHONE_PROJECTION = { Phone.NUMBER, };
private static final String PHONE_LOOKUP_KEY_SELECTION = Data.LOOKUP_KEY
            + "=?" + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
            + "'";
public String getPhoneNumber(String lookupKey) {
        String result = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    PHONE_PROJECTION, PHONE_LOOKUP_KEY_SELECTION,
                    new String[] { lookupKey }, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                result = cursor.getString(0);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```